# Python nan showing up in molecular gas simulation

Tags: python, numpy, simulation, physics

I am writing a script which is supposed to simulate the interaction of gas molecules, using the Lennard-Jones potential. I am facing two issues.

1. When I use `np.sqrt()` to calculate the distance between my molecules I get only lists consisting of `nan` values... which isn't very helpful.
2. I got rid of this issue as after I replaced `np.sqrt()` with simply `()**0.5`. Yet I am still getting wrong results.

The line which is here discussed is the following one `dist12 = (r12[0]**2 + r12[1]**2)**0.5`. **However getting rid of the nan warning didn't fully resolve my issues**, because later I am checking `if dist12 == 0: return 0, 0`  Which leads position lists consisting - apart from the lists of the first four particles - to lists which contain mostly zeros.

So something is probably wrong with the code flow. But I am unable to find what's the issue. So let me first shortly describe the intended code flow.

1. Particle initialization, 16 particles are initialized form the `class Czastka` with their corresponding initial conditions.
2. The `simulate()` function iterates `num_step = 1000` through the particles list and calculates the sum of forces acting on each particle as a result of the interaction with other particles. For this the `lennard_jones_forces(x1, y1, x2, y2)` function is used. The condition is applied that if the particles are over `2.5*sigma` apart then they don't feel any force of attraction.
3. Using the function `leapforg_single_step(particle, force_x_comp, force_y_comp):` the new positions and velocities are calculated.
4. Which then are appended to the list of the particles positions using `p1.update_position(p1_x_next, p1_y_next, box_size)`. **Here also the periodic boundary conditions are checked.** The idea behind them is that if the particle will leave the frame/box in which the gas is simulated/contained. It will appear from the other side this is achieved using modular division `self.x = new_x % box_size`.

As I said I don't understand what causes the nan errors nor why I get in the end mostly zeros in my position lists? Here is my full code:

```
import numpy as np

#Inicjalizacja paramatrów
particle_num, box_size, eps, sigma = 16, 8.0, 1.0, 1.0
dt, temp, k_B, m, M = 0.0001, 2.5, 1, 1, 1
radius = sigma/2


class Czastka:
    #Inicjalizacja danych cząstki
    def __init__(self, radius, x_pos, y_pos, x_vel, y_vel):
        #Składowe wartości wektorowych
        self.x, self.y = x_pos, y_pos
        self.vx, self.vy = x_vel, y_vel

        """
        NOTE: The goal of the simulation in the end is to get only these 4 lists
        """
        #Positions lists
        self.x_positions_lst = []
        self.y_positions_lst = []

        #Velocity lists
        self.x_velocity_lst = []
        self.y_velocity_lst = []

    def append_postions(self, x_pos, y_pos):
        self.x_positions_lst.append(x_pos)
        self.y_positions_lst.append(y_pos)

    def update_velocities(self, x_vel, y_vel):
        self.x_velocity_lst.append(x_vel)
        self.y_velocity_lst.append(y_vel)

    # Stosujemy periodyczne warunki brzegowe poprzez liczenie modułowe
    def update_position(self, new_x, new_y, box_size):
        self.x = new_x % box_size
        self.y = new_y % box_size
        self.append_postions(self.x, self.y)

# Inicjalizacja cząstek
initial_x, initial_y = [1, 3, 5, 7], [1, 3, 5, 7]
initial_vx, initial_vy = [1, 1, 2, 0.5], [1, 0.5, 0.25, 4]

particle_lst = []
for i in range(0, 4):
    for j in range(0, 4):
        particle_lst.append(Czastka(radius, initial_x[j], initial_y[j], initial_vx[j], initial_vy[j]))
#print(len(particle_lst))



#Siła jaka działa na skutek odziaływań w potencjale Lennard-Jonesa
def lennard_jones_forces(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    global sigma, eps

    #Obliczenia pomocnicze
    r12 = [x2-x1, y2-y1]
    dist12 = (r12[0]**2 + r12[1]**2)**0.5
    print(r12[0], ' ', r12[1])
    if dist12 == 0:
        return 0, 0

    # Calculate Lennard-Jones force
    sigma_over_dist12 = sigma / dist12
    sigma_over_dist12_14 = sigma_over_dist12 ** 14
    sigma_over_dist12_8 = sigma_over_dist12 ** 8

    Force21 = -(48 * eps / (sigma ** 2)) * (sigma_over_dist12_14 - 0.5 * sigma_over_dist12_8)
    Force21_x = Force21 * r12[0]
    Force21_y = Force21 * r12[1]

    #W tym momecie nasza funkcja jest gotowa ALE musimy sprawdzić czy zachodzi warunek odcięcia
    #Żeby zwiększyć wydajnośc obliczniową powinno się dokonać tego sprwdzenia, przed obliczniem sił
    if np.isnan(Force21_x) or np.isnan(Force21_y):
        print(Force21_x, ' ', Force21_y)
        print("Nan detected in force calculation")

    if dist12 > (2.5*sigma):
        #print('Cut off')
        Force21_x, Force21_y = 0, 0
        return Force21_x, Force21_y
    else:
        #print('Normal operation')
        return Force21_x, Force21_y


# Obliczanie poprzez wykorzystanie algorytmu żabki nowych współrzędnych
def leapforg_single_step(particle, force_x_comp, force_y_comp):
    global dt, m

    #Obliczanie pół-krokowych prędkości
    vx_half = particle.vx + 0.5 * (force_x_comp / m) * dt
    vy_half = particle.vy + 0.5 * (force_y_comp / m) * dt

    #Obliczanie pół-krokowych położeń
    x_next = particle.x + vx_half * dt
    y_next = particle.y + vy_half * dt

    #Obliczanie nowych prędkości
    vx_next = vx_half + 0.5 * (force_x_comp / m) * dt
    vy_next = vy_half + 0.5 * (force_y_comp / m) * dt

    return x_next, y_next, vx_next, vy_next



def simulate():
    global box_size
    num_steps = 1000

    #Cała symulacja składa się z num_steps kroków
    for step in range(num_steps):
        #Obliczmy sumę sił działającą na każdą cząstkę
        for i, p1 in enumerate(particle_lst):
            force_x, force_y = 0, 0
            for j, p2 in enumerate(particle_lst):
                if i != j:
                    # Obliczam sume sił działająca na cząsteki p1 (bez interakcji z samym sobą)
                    f_x, f_y = lennard_jones_forces(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y)
                    force_x += f_x
                    force_y += f_y

            p1_x_next, p1_y_next, p1_vx_next, p1_vy_next = leapforg_single_step(p1, force_x, force_y)
            p1.update_position(p1_x_next, p1_y_next, box_size)
            p1.update_velocities(p1_vx_next, p1_vy_next)

simulate()


def simulation_results():
    for i, particle in enumerate(particle_lst):
        print('Particle number: {}. List lenght: {} and x-positions list: {}'.format(i, len(particle.x_positions_lst), particle.x_positions_lst))
simulation_results()

def animation():
    pass
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Cheers!

Comment: No, I don't think anything is wrong with your code flow, but with your simulative setup. It should never be possible to have a distance of 0; that's non-physical. You need to re-think how your system is modelled.

Comment: You have sixteen particles but only four initial positions. That is the actual problem.

Comment: Please do not edit the question to redefine the problem that is occurring in the code; that invalidates the answer. The "yielding constant values" problem is separate and requires a new question.

Comment: I have rolled the question back. You can borrow from the edit history to write the new question if needed.

Answer (score 1):

A zero distance is non-physical. You have a probably-incorrect initial iteration that produces 16 particles from only 4 initial position values. When I fix this, there are no NaNs even when I make detection of same more noisy by raising an exception. There are other things to improve here (you're not at all using Numpy correctly).

```py
import numpy as np

# Inicjalizacja paramatrów
particle_num, box_size, eps, sigma = 16, 8.0, 1.0, 1.0
dt, temp, k_B, m, M = 0.0001, 2.5, 1, 1, 1
radius = sigma/2


class Particle:
    # Inicjalizacja danych cząstki
    def __init__(self, radius: float, x_pos: float, y_pos: float, x_vel: float, y_vel: float) -> None:
        # Składowe wartości wektorowych
        self.x, self.y = x_pos, y_pos
        self.vx, self.vy = x_vel, y_vel

        """
        NOTE: The goal of the simulation in the end is to get only these 4 lists
        """
        # Positions lists
        self.x_positions_lst: list[float] = []
        self.y_positions_lst: list[float] = []

        # Velocity lists
        self.x_velocity_lst: list[float] = []
        self.y_velocity_lst: list[float] = []

    def append_postions(self, x_pos: float, y_pos: float) -> None:
        self.x_positions_lst.append(x_pos)
        self.y_positions_lst.append(y_pos)

    def update_velocities(self, x_vel: float, y_vel: float) -> None:
        self.x_velocity_lst.append(x_vel)
        self.y_velocity_lst.append(y_vel)

    # Stosujemy periodyczne warunki brzegowe poprzez liczenie modułowe
    def update_position(self, new_x: float, new_y: float, box_size: float) -> None:
        self.x = new_x % box_size
        self.y = new_y % box_size
        self.append_postions(self.x, self.y)

    # Obliczanie poprzez wykorzystanie algorytmu żabki nowych współrzędnych
    def leapfrog_single_step(self, force_x_comp: float, force_y_comp: float) -> tuple[
        float,  # x next
        float,  # y next
        float,  # vx next
        float,  # vy next
    ]:
        # Obliczanie pół-krokowych prędkości
        vx_half = self.vx + 0.5 * (force_x_comp / m) * dt
        vy_half = self.vy + 0.5 * (force_y_comp / m) * dt

        # Obliczanie pół-krokowych położeń
        x_next = self.x + vx_half * dt
        y_next = self.y + vy_half * dt

        # Obliczanie nowych prędkości
        vx_next = vx_half + 0.5 * (force_x_comp / m) * dt
        vy_next = vy_half + 0.5 * (force_y_comp / m) * dt

        return x_next, y_next, vx_next, vy_next


# Siła jaka działa na skutek odziaływań w potencjale Lennard-Jonesa
def lennard_jones_forces(
    x1: float, y1: float, x2: float, y2: float,
) -> tuple[float, float]:
    # Obliczenia pomocnicze
    r12 = [x2-x1, y2-y1]
    dist12 = (r12[0]**2 + r12[1]**2)**0.5
    # print(r12[0], ' ', r12[1])
    if dist12 == 0:
        raise ValueError('A zero distance is non-physical')

    # Calculate Lennard-Jones force
    sigma_over_dist12 = sigma / dist12
    sigma_over_dist12_14 = sigma_over_dist12 ** 14
    sigma_over_dist12_8 = sigma_over_dist12 ** 8

    Force21 = -(48 * eps / (sigma ** 2)) * (sigma_over_dist12_14 - 0.5 * sigma_over_dist12_8)
    Force21_x = Force21 * r12[0]
    Force21_y = Force21 * r12[1]

    # W tym momecie nasza funkcja jest gotowa ALE musimy sprawdzić czy zachodzi warunek odcięcia
    # Żeby zwiększyć wydajnośc obliczniową powinno się dokonać tego sprwdzenia, przed obliczniem sił
    if np.isnan(Force21_x) or np.isnan(Force21_y):
        raise ValueError(f"Nan detected in force calculation: {Force21_x} {Force21_y}")

    if dist12 > (2.5*sigma):
        # print('Cut off')
        Force21_x, Force21_y = 0, 0
        return Force21_x, Force21_y
    else:
        # print('Normal operation')
        return Force21_x, Force21_y


def simulate(particle_lst: list[Particle]) -> None:
    num_steps = 1000

    # Cała symulacja składa się z num_steps kroków
    for step in range(num_steps):
        # Obliczmy sumę sił działającą na każdą cząstkę
        for i, p1 in enumerate(particle_lst):
            force_x, force_y = 0, 0
            for j, p2 in enumerate(particle_lst):
                if i != j:
                    # Obliczam sume sił działająca na cząsteki p1 (bez interakcji z samym sobą)
                    f_x, f_y = lennard_jones_forces(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y)
                    force_x += f_x
                    force_y += f_y

            p1_x_next, p1_y_next, p1_vx_next, p1_vy_next = p1.leapfrog_single_step(force_x, force_y)
            p1.update_position(p1_x_next, p1_y_next, box_size)
            p1.update_velocities(p1_vx_next, p1_vy_next)


def simulation_results(particle_lst: list[Particle]) -> None:
    for i, particle in enumerate(particle_lst):
        print(
            f'Particle number: {i}. '
            f'List length: {len(particle.x_positions_lst)} and '
            f'x-positions list: {particle.x_positions_lst}'
        )


def main() -> None:
    # Inicjalizacja cząstek
    initial_x, initial_y = [1, 3, 5, 7], [1, 3, 5, 7]
    initial_vx, initial_vy = [1, 1, 2, 0.5], [1, 0.5, 0.25, 4]

    particle_lst = []
    for x, y, vx, vy in zip(initial_x, initial_y, initial_vx, initial_vy):
        particle_lst.append(Particle(radius, x, y, vx, vy))
    # print(len(particle_lst))

    simulate(particle_lst)
    simulation_results(particle_lst)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Yes you are right. The initialization is wrong. I have added an initialization function. This resolved the issue of both nan and zero values. However still the code return positions which barely change...

Comment: I have edited my question so that it now includes the modified code with the proper initialization.

Comment: After I tried to use your solution to the problem (without changing the initialization procedure) I unfortunately get the following error message: ```line 46, in Particle float,  # vy next TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable```

Comment: Upgrade Python.